# Hegel's counter proof of the old Logic

Tags: philosophy-of-logic

In his book on Logic,Hegel makes a counter proof of the old way of defining Logic. I have trouble understanding in which way Aristotle or Descartes were wrong according to him.
Could someone explain?
Thanks
edit:
It is previously said that Aristotle bounds logic and metaphysics together,then a little a passage from the book:"

> After having considered the middle term as a specy and his quantitative relationships with the extremes,he considers the proposition from the point of view of the cause and the essence,posing the essence as the middle term or the absolute principle of the proof.

It seems there is a contradiction because Aristotle only studies the quantities and not the qualities of the objects so not the essence.

Comment: A more precise reference, please.

Comment: I edited my  question. And I must say I would also be in interesting in the consideration of genus,specy and middle term in Hegel's Logic because those concepts are to me pretty obscure.

Comment: For Aristotle [essence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-metaphysics/#SubsEsse) is also a cause.

Comment: Having said that, is it Hegel?s Science of Logic ? What page ?

Comment: Hegel treat *syllogism* in Ch.3 of [Science of Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=hvFzyR3mNpQC&printsec=frontcover). I'm not an expert of Hegel and I assume that its treatment is "convoluted"... but I do not think that he does not understand the "formal" machinery of [syllogism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-logic/).

Comment: It's in the first traduction in French of Hegel's Logic first volume. It seems it was made in 1859. I don't know if you can read French and I can't find an equivalent in English.

Comment: Do you know the basic structure of [Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism): terms, premises, major and minor, etc ?

Comment: Not all the aspects indeed. I've juste started in Logic but maybe Hegel is not the best choice to begin with it.

Comment: If you are interested into [Hegel’s Dialectics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hegel-dialectics/), it is (maybe) the right place; if you are interested into Formal Logic, definitely not (and neither Descartes): Aristotle is much better.

Comment: @maths_mz If you really want to understand logic, the most effective way is to start with Aristotle, Prior Analytics. Once you are certain to understand Aristotle's syllogistic, you can move on to contemporary authors, those who understand something about logic, Tarski in particular.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I'll start with Aristotle!